# Why doesn't this code for prepending to a linked list create a cycle?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm learning about linked lists and the article I'm reading shows how to create a linked list and prepend it to the front of the list. Here's what they say is the way:

> 1) *Allocate*: Allocate the new node in the heap and set its `.data` to
>   whatever needs to be stored.
>
> ```
>     struct node* newNode;
>     newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
>     newNode->data = data_client_wants_stored;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> 2) *Link Next*: Set the `.next` pointer of the new node to point to the current
>   first node of the list. This is actually just a pointer assignment — remember: "assigning one pointer to another makes them point to the same
>   thing."
>
> ```
>     newNode->next = head;
> ```
>
> ---
>
> 3) *Link Head*: Change the head pointer to point to the new node, so it is
>   now the first node in the list.
>
> ```
>     head = newNode;
> ```

Here's what I don't understand about this process:

When we assign the `next` pointer to head, and then assign `head` to `newNode`, isn't that the same as setting `next` to `newNode`? Because the second step says assigning to one pointer makes them point to the same thing. When we reassign `head` to point to `newNode`, doesn't that change `newNode->next` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When we reassign head to point to newNode, doesn't that change newNode->next as well?

Fortunately, the answer is no. Let's take an example with some simple `int` variables:

```
int a = 42;
int b = 15;
b = a;
a = 0; // <-- Here
```

After we set `a = 0`, the value of `b` will still be 42, which was set in the previous line. The reason is that writing `a = b` in the previous line doesn't permanently link the values of `a` and `b`; instead, it's a one-shot operation of "change `b`'s value to be the value of `a` right now."

As a parallel, in these lines:

```
newNode->next = head;
head = newNode;
```

The first line, `newNode->next = head;`, means "change the value of `newNode->next` to be the value of `head` at this instant in time." Consequently, `newNode`'s `next` pointer will point to the start of the linked list.  When you then execute `head = newNode;`, the value of `head` is then updated so that it now points to `newNode`. The fact that we set `newNode->next = head` in the previous line doesn't then cause `newNode->next` to be rewired to point to `newNode` itself, just in the same way that writing `a = 0` in the `int` example didn't change the value of `b`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean `15` instead of `42` right? In "After we set..."

Comment: @JoeDF Oh whoops, yes. Let me fix that.

Comment: This helps a lot. I don't have any confusion about it now, thanks.